# Python script for outputting JSON has wrong output for attribute-value pair

Tags: python, json, azure-functions

I'm writing a Python script to output some JSON files to Cosmos DB on Azure. My script looks as follows:

```
import logging
import uuid
import json

import azure.functions as func


def main(event: func.EventHubEvent, message: func.Out[func.Document]) -> None:
    event_body = event.get_body().decode('utf-8')

    logging.info('Python event trigger function processed an event item: %s',event_body)

    data = {
        "value": event_body,
        "insertion_time": event_body
        }

    message.set(func.Document.from_json(json.dumps(data)))
```

The output is written like:

```
{
    "value": "{\n  \"value\": \"66\",\n  \"insertion_time\": \"2020-06-02T05:50:00+00:00\"\n}",
    "insertion_time": "{\n  \"value\": \"66\",\n  \"insertion_time\": \"2020-06-02T05:50:00+00:00\"\n}"  
}
```

However, I'd like it to be like:

```
{
    "value": "66",
    "insertion_time": "2020-06-02T05:50:00+00:00"  
}
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: `"value: event_body.value`  and `insertion_time: event_body.insertion_time`  => where you are creating `data` variable

Comment: or directly => `func.Document.from_json(json.dumps(event_body))` . Dont need to create `data` n then dump that

Comment: @Sowjanya I don’t think `json.dumps` is necessary either.

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat I get the following error: `Exception: NameError: name 'insertion_time' is not defined` when changing to `event_body`.

Comment: it is `insertion_time`  .  not `intertion_time`  .

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat Sorry - my bad! However, not I get the error: `Exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'`

Comment: so your `event_body` is a string => convert it to dict/json before doing `event_body.value`

Comment: or just directly  dump `event_body` as i mentioned before

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `event_body` appears to be a JSON string which already contains exactly what you want. It appears you don’t need to do anything and just use it directly:

```
message.set(func.Document.from_json(event_body))
```